# How to access a specific method in a loop?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, tree, twig

Let's say I have a Category entity, a Person entity, and these two are related by a Contract Entity.

In my view, I need to display a category with all its subcategories with the number of persons

For example :
when the user is on the page to view "the category A", I would like he/she sees that :

```
Category A                  10 persons
  subcategory a.1            4 persons
  subcategory a.2            6 persons
```

So in my show.html.twig, I would write :

```
{{ category.title }}  {{ nb_persons }}
{% for child in children %}
   {{ child.title }} //{{ child.getNbPersons() }}??, how to get the number of persons for each child ?
{% endfor %}
```

Here's my CategoryController.php

```
public function showAction($id_category)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Category');
    $this->param['category']= $repo->find($id);
    $this->param['nb_persons'] = $repo->getNbPersonsByCategory($id_category);
    $this->param['children'] = $repo->children($this->param['category'], true, 'title');

return $this->render('MyBundle:Category:show.html.twig', $this->param);
}
```

But to display the number of persons for each subcategory(child) I need to use a method like child.getNbPersons(), but this would force me to use a repository function in my entity Category.php and this is a bad practice I think.
What can I do ?

Comment: I don't think entity repository methods are a bad practice. They are very useful for such situations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I need to access the container to get the entity manager in my entity Category.php, I tried this $em=$this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager(); but the container seems not defined here.. How could I access it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465237/doctrine2-best-practice-should-entities-use-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to totally isolate model from everything else. That is, model is not aware controller, repositories etc.

Regarding your problem I would rather construct an appropriate object (well an `array`) within controller and pass it to `Twig` as it is and that `array` should hold all the info needed precalculated. That way, if you have a lot of categories (and/or subcategories) you would have to exec database query only once, opposed to calling the repository from model method where each call would require a single query.

Hope this helps... ;)