# Symfony2 Doctrine Get reference based on attribute

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

in my Symfony2/Doctrine2 project I have an entity `Person` which has a birth date. I have another entity `Agegroup` which stores a name and some more information for a group based on the age in years.

Example:
`Person` Name: xy Date: 1980-05-06
`Agegroup`: From: 1  To: 10
`Agegroup`: From: 11  To: 20
`Agegroup`: From: 21  To: 30

I want to get the Agegroup which a person currently belongs to, from within the entity (based on current date).

i.e. :$person->getCurrentAgeGroup()

Therefore I would have to access another repository class from within the entity, which is obviously not a good thing to do.

Is there a way to implement this kind of functionality?

I read [Using EntityManager inside Doctrine 2.0 entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673270/service-objects-with-doctrine2-and-symfony2)
which could be a solution to the problem. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution to implementent this. Do I have to inject the service somehow into the entity?

Maybe there are other best practices for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good style to put the entity manager into your entities. A better approach would be to create a custom `AgegroupRepository` that has a method `getAgegroup(Person $person)`

Another approach would be to make the age group a property of `Person` (with getters and setters), create a custom `PersonRepository` and modify the `find()` method to instantiate the correct instance of `Agegroup` when looking for a person.

Your entity objects should only store data and business rules and should not concern themselves with the storage of the information. This is what repositories are for.